# Any good FDF tutorial?

Tags: forms, pdf, fdf

Does any one know of a good tutorial on how to fill a pdf document fields using the fdf file format? I could find some but mostly in php (which I don't know).

If it's in any of the following programming languages, that'll be great:

VB6
C#
VB.NET
Visual Foxpro

Thanks in advance,

EGB

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! The FDF toolkit has several sample projects and documentation.

It can be downloaded from: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html